# Reuse code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have the following `datepicker` settings:

```
 startDate.datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                container: container,
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
            })

            endDate.datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                container: container,
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
            })
```

As you can see, they have the same settings. How can I reuse these settings, so I can reduce the size of my code?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `params` block or the like, then use the spread operator in each place I need to used the object so I could make simple additions if need be.  A bit simpler, cleaner.

```
let params = {
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                container: container,
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
            };

startDate.datepicker({ ...params })
endDate.datepicker({ ...params, additionalThing: true })
```

Comment: There's no need to use the spread operator for the first one, except for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing an object to the `datepicker()` function you can do this:

```
var settings = {
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true
};
startDate.datepicker(settings);
endDate.datepicker(settings;
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to put the options in a variable. You can also combine the jQuery objects.

```
startDate.add(endDate).datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the options object as a variable and pass it into the pickers.

```
var datePickerOptions = {
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  container: container,
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
}
startDate.datepicker(datePickerOptions)

endDate.datepicker(datePickerOptions)
```